# Is it possible to pass an object thru ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to pass an object to a Controller? For example, I have ActionLink and I am pass the Model as Id.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
            "Next", 
            "Step",
            new { StepId = 2, id = Model }, 
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "stepContainer" }, 
            new { @class = "button" })
```

And the Controller has

```
public ActionResult Step(int StepId, object id)
{
}
```

How can I do this? Is this silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass objects like this. An ActionLink helper generates an anchor tag which when clicked sends a GET request to the server. In this GET request you will have to include everything that you want the server to receive as part of the query string.

Another possibility is to only send the id of this model so that the controller action can fetch it back from the datastore from which it initially fetched it when rendering the page:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Next", 
    "Step",
    new { 
        StepId = 2,
        id = Model.Id
    }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "stepContainer" }, 
    new { @class = "button" }
)
```

and in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Step(int StepId, int id)
{
    var model = Repository.GetModel(id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to -1, because... false... you can pass objects in like this...  You would have to serialize to JSON, and deserialize with a custom model binder, but it is possible.

Comment: In principle, I agree that he should be fetching an object by id, but that "No" in the first part bugs me...

Comment: @JohnGietzen, sure but why serializing and deserializing something that you already have on the server?

Comment: No, of course I agree with you.  But maybe it is on the client side, and he is just testing the waters for the feasibility of sending objects this way?

Comment: @JohnGietzen, no, it cannot be on the client side because he uses the keyword Model when generating his ActionLink which is purely server side.

Comment: overall what I am trying to do is to set up a "Step by Step" wizard, which is going to have the Model as the common thing throughout each Partial Views (STEP 1-N). i need to pass the Model to each partial view as they get updated. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What @DarinDimitrov is suggesting works for me, but I can't save the information save in the previous step.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with custom model binding.

That is a subject that is a little bit bigger than an answer on StackOverflow can realistically cover, but you can certainly do it.

You would do something like this:

```
public class CrazyPantsModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Add code here to deserialize your object from the query string...

        return yourObject;
    }
}
```

And you would register it in the Global.asax with a call like:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(object)] = new CrazyPantsModelBinder();
```

However, I would have to answer that, yes, this is somewhat silly.

If you are looking for some google-mojo to find out how to do this, I would use the terms "json model binder" to search.